# Run Automator-generated .app from ant?

Tags: ant, automator

I used the Automator tool on my mac to generate a .app file (well a directory, to be more precise).  I am trying to execute this .app in an ant build.xml, but it gives me a file/directory not found error.  I tried running exec on both the .app folder and on the "Application Stub" file buried inside, but both produced the same error.  This should be straightforward, but I'm new to both automator and ant so I don't know the right syntax here.

More specifically, how do I run the task `open MyApp.app` in a build.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<exec executable="open">
    <arg value="MyApp.app" />
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following:

open -a MyApp.app

or

open -a MyApp

both should work.

I have noticed though that my apps created with Automator seem to have "funny" names for awhile.  You can see "good names" in the Finder, but when I try to open their AppleScript dictionaries from AppleScript editor, the names are some kind of hex codes or something.  (I'd give you a screen-shot but I don't have enough reputation points here yet to post an image.)

You could try opening up some other app from Ant see if that works.

Comment: How do I structure that in terms of an exec command?  Or should I be using a different command?

Comment: I believe that you would use the "open" command instead of using the "exec" command.

Comment: I got `Problem: failed to create task or type open`

Comment: I'm sorry, you are talking about ant build scripts and I was thinking about the "exec" command run from the command-line.  I would have gotten back to you sooner but I didn't know what you meant exactly.  Also, it would be nice to get full examples, not all of your code, but code that is pared down that shows the problem yet is complete enough to be run: http://ideone.com/tVSYiJ  invoke with the following command from the command-line: ant RunTextEdit.  Will you also do me a favor and vote my answers up?